# How to save/load part of a model in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

I have made an autoencoder in TensorFlow 2. Firstly, I need to train the model on a dataset. After training the autoencoder, I want to use the encoder part of the autoencoder for a different dataset while retaining the trained weights. Is there a way to do so? I couldn't find one. Any guidelines would be helpful. Here is a rough autoencoder that I am trying to use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model

def Autoencoder():
    # Encoder
    inp = Input(shape=(100,))
    x = Dense(1000)(inp)
    x = Dense(500)(x)
    code = Dense(10)(x)

    # Decoder    
    x = Dense(500)(code)
    x = Dense(1000)(x)
    out = Dense(100)(x)

    model = Model(inp,out)
    return model

autoencoder = Autoencoder()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the encoder part you can write a CustomCheckpoint class and save the encoder like below.

```
class CustomCheckpoint(Callback):

def __init__(self, filepath, encoder):
    self.monitor = 'val_loss'
    self.monitor_op = np.less
    self.best = np.Inf

    self.filepath = filepath
    self.encoder = encoder

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    current = logs.get(self.monitor)
    if self.monitor_op(current, self.best):
        self.best = current
        # self.encoder.save_weights(self.filepath, overwrite=True)
        self.encoder.save(self.filepath, overwrite=True) # Whichever you prefer
```

To load the encoder part from the saved weights, you can do something like below code.

```
from keras.models import load_model
autoencoder = load_model("path_to_file")
encoder = Model(autoencoder.layers[0].input, autoencoder.layers[1].output)
```